# How do I recompile a single Linux kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I need to build `mmc_block.ko` but with `MMC_BLOCK_MINORS=16`. I do not wish to build the entire kernel. I am using Ubuntu 15.10. How do I do this?

Comment: You may provide a module parameter for that. No need to recompile. `mmcblk.perdev_minors`

Comment: @AndyShevchenko That does not work. Unmounting all partitions, running `rmmod mmc_block`, running `modprobe mmc_block perdev_minors=16`, and running `cat /sys/module/mmc_block/mmc_block.perdev_minors` returns `8`.

Comment: Interesting, do you see the difference between `mmcblk.perdev_minors` and `perdev_minors`?  Check this one: http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-mmc/msg32391.html. Does your kernel have one? I think the answer is *no*.

Answer (score 2):

Dpending on how the Makefile has been written, a module can be compiled out of the kernel tree or in the kernel tree.

Concerning your specific example, I assume the module is the one shipped with the kernel and therefore the Makefile has been written for in-tree compilation. In this case, you can just type `make modules` to rebuild the module, provided that the kernel has been already compiled (which is a mandatory condition also for out-of-the-tree compilation).

Comment: I need to rebuild one module, not all of them. And I need some more detail. Do I have to recompile the kernel?

Comment: Formally the answer is correct, though the topic starter does not need module recompilation in this particular case!

Comment: I understand. However the title is "How do I *recompile* a single Linux kernel module?"